Find a bounded real sequence, whose range has exactly one accumulation point, but which is not convergent

Example of bounded sequence on $ \mathbb{R}$ s.t. the set $\{X_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ has exactly one accumulation point but $X_n$ is not convergent

My thoughts: Since Xn is bounded it has convergent subsequence. So Xn must be a branch sequence. We can take on branch for instance X_2n=1(so there’s our bounded and convergent subsequence) and for the other part, for instance: X_2n-1 we need one bounded but not convergent subsequence which also has no accumulation points. That’s the part I’m stuck. Could I maybe take something which goes back and forth in the unit interval? Or maybe a series which diverges?(but then how could it be bounded?)

Trying to put the whole text of the question in the title just makes it hard to read. If you really need to copy the exact text, summarize the question in the title and put the question in the body off the question.

@AnneBauval it does! Thank you very much. I don’t know how you did it. I was searching on the web about 30 minutes now for something that could answer it

@ThomasAndrews thank you! I’ll keep this in mind for my next post!

@AnneBauval oh sorry I’m an idiot! Didn’t notice you were the one who answered it. Thanks again. So the basic thing to grasp here is that while the sequence can have two accumulation points, only one of them belongs in set A and therefore we have what the exercise wants

@AnneBauval Sorry I just saw more meticulously the link you provided and it doesn’t answer my question per se. My version of the exercise asks for set A={Xn : $ n \in \mathbb{N} $} to have one accumulation point not A={1/n : $ n \in \mathbb{N} $}

Try taking any convergent sequence and sprinkle in infinitely many other entries tending to infinity to mess up the convergence.

@JairTaylor but how would that be bounded?

oh, I misread the question.  In that case, the sequence must have an additional accumulation point. But as a set, it may only have one (see answers to the other question.)

@ JairTaylor I’m not sure if I understand correctly why the set of the sequence has only one accumulation point. Is it some sort of a mapping? So that the subsequence which is 1 is actually an isolated point of the image? And therefore not an accumulation point?

My link does answer the question. For my sequence, ${x_n:n\in\Bbb N}$ is equal to ${1/n:n\in\Bbb N}$. Don't confuse the sequence and its set $A$ of values. As stressed and detailed in my answer (and in the link therein), the accumulation points of the set $A$ are not the accumulation points of the sequence. Though the name (accumulation point) is the same, the definition are not.
